# How can I transfer something that was entered in an html text field to a js variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to program an autofill which automatically transmits information to a website.
Now, I want to develop an html code by being able to enter all the necessary information and then transfer it in the text box on the website.

Example :

Js code :

```
var email = "john@gmail.com";
document.getElementById("checkout_email").value = email;
```

Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<input type="text" placeholder="email">

<html>
```

How do I get it now when I enter a new email address in the input field that it will be transferred to the var email in the javascript?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: add 'change' event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get it now when I enter a new email address in the input
> field that it will be transferred to the var email in the javascript?

You can use an eventlistener to listen when your input value changes and then read the value propety of the element and store it to your email variable in js.

Try it out in the snippet type in a value and then press enter

```js
document.getElementById("mail").addEventListener('change', function(){
let email = document.getElementById("mail").value;
document.getElementById("outp").innerHTML = email;
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<input type="text" placeholder="email" id="mail">
<p id="outp"></p>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get your email variable updated as the user is typing, then use the `oninput` event listener:

```js
var email = "";
var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");

emailInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
  email = emailInput.value;
  console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<input id="email"/>
```

Alternatively, you may want to update the variable only when the user is done typing. In this case, listen for `change` rather than `input`:

```js
var email = "";
var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");

emailInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  email = emailInput.value;
  console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<input id="email"/>
```